# Dot net Open Auth Provider

Tags: openid, dotnetopenauth

I am new to open Id i want to implement my own openid provider backed with windows authentication.

I have tried to run the example given by dotnetopenauth for creating your own provider the example runs but what is the endpoint url or how would i get the endpoint url for consuming this provider.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like OpenID is the solution for you. You may wish to consider using DotNetOpenAuth authorisation server (OAUTH) backed by ADFS for user authentication.